# How to retrieve property values of a node in py2neo

Tags: py2neo

I,m creating a graph database of geometric shapes and nodes contain a property called "type" to indicate whether that shape is a Triangle, Circle or square.I want to retrieve the type of every node and use it in IF condition as follow.

```
Results = g.run("START n=node(*)  RETURN n.type as type")
for Result in Results:
     if Result.type == 'TRINGLE':
        print("It is a Triange")
     elif Result.type == 'CIRCLE':
         print("It is a Circle")
     else:
        print("It is a Square")
```

when run this code it is showing an error like this-
if Result.type == 'TRINGLE':
AttributeError: 'Record' object has no attribute 'type'

can anyone please tell me that are there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `record["type"]` instead of `record.type`.